# why does scikitlearn says F1 score is ill-defined with FN bigger than 0?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn

I run a python program that calls `sklearn.metrics`'s methods to calculate precision and F1 score. Here is the output when there is no predicted sample:

```
/xxx/py2-scikit-learn/0.15.2-comp6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/metr\
ics/metrics.py:1771: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)

/xxx/py2-scikit-learn/0.15.2-comp6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sklearn/metr\
ics/metrics.py:1771: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
```

When there is no predicted sample, it means that TP+FP is 0, so

- precision (defined as TP/(TP+FP)) is 0/0, not defined,
- F1 score (defined as 2TP/(2TP+FP+FN)) is 0 if FN is not zero.

In my case, `sklearn.metrics` also returns the accuracy as 0.8, and recall as 0. So FN is not zero.

But why does scikilearn says F1 is ill-defined?

What is the definition of F1 used by Scikilearn?

Answer (score 48):

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/classification.py

> F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

precision = TP/(TP+FP) as you've just said if predictor doesn't predicts positive class at all - precision is 0.

recall = TP/(TP+FN), in case if predictor doesn't predict positive class - TP is 0 - recall is 0.

So now you are dividing 0/0.

Comment: I understand this warning is because some classes in the test never get predicted. What I don't understand is a way to understand why a classification algorithm may behave such way. For example, I fitted an `SVC` and a `RF` classifiers on same data, `RF` doesn't predict a particular class in all runs of experiments.

Answer (score 20):

**Precision, Recall, F1-score** and **Accuracy** calculation

```
- In a given image of Dogs and Cats

  * Total Dogs - 12  D = 12
  * Total Cats - 8   C = 8

- Computer program predicts

  * Dogs - 8  
    5 are actually Dogs   T.P = 5
    3 are not             F.P = 3    
  * Cats - 12
    6 are actually Cats   T.N = 6 
    6 are not             F.N = 6

- Calculation

  * Precision = T.P / (T.P + F.P) => 5 / (5 + 3)
  * Recall    = T.P / D           => 5 / 12

  * F1 = 2 * (Precision * Recall) / (Precision + Recall)
  * F1 = 0.5

  * Accuracy = T.P + T.N / P + N
  * Accuracy = 0.55
```

Wikipedia [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)