# Prepare SKlearn model with Isolation Forest to deploy on Google Cloud

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

I'm new to machine learning world and working on a project in which I have trained a model for fraud detection using SKlearn.I'm training the model in this way as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

# define a random state
state = 1

# define the outlier detection method
classifiers = {
    "Isolation Forest": IsolationForest(max_samples=len(X),
                                       contamination=outlier_fraction,
                                       random_state=state),
    "Local Outlier Factor": LocalOutlierFactor(
    n_neighbors = 20,
    contamination = outlier_fraction)
}

# fit the model
n_outliers = len(Fraud)

for i, (clf_name, clf) in enumerate(classifiers.items()):

    # fit te data and tag outliers
    if clf_name == "Local Outlier Factor":
        y_pred = clf.fit_predict(X)
        scores_pred = clf.negative_outlier_factor_
    else:
        clf.fit(X)
        scores_pred = clf.decision_function(X)
        y_pred = clf.predict(X)

    # Reshape the prediction values to 0 for valid and 1 for fraudulent
    y_pred[y_pred == 1] = 0
    y_pred[y_pred == -1] = 1

    n_errors = (y_pred != Y).sum()

    # run classification metrics 
    print('{}:{}'.format(clf_name, n_errors))
    print(accuracy_score(Y, y_pred ))
    print(classification_report(Y, y_pred ))
```

And it returns the following output:

```
Isolation Forest:7
0.93
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.97      0.96      0.96        95
      1       0.33      0.40      0.36         5

avg / total   0.94      0.93      0.93       100

Local Outlier Factor:9
0.91
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.96      0.95      0.95        95
          1       0.17      0.20      0.18         5

avg / total       0.92      0.91      0.91       100
```

Now the confusing part is it's deployment, after struggling a lot I have decided to deploy and serve it with the help of a flask web service, but don't understand how I can pass the input to my `predict` method here to get a prediction?

**Is there something have been done in a wrong way?**

**How can I pass the input to my `predict` method here?**

Help me, please!
Any resource for step by step guide to its deployment to google cloud will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may want to read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/quickstart)

Comment: Hi @MaxU, it's really helpful for the purpose of deployment, but I'm still confused about how will I pas the new input to this model for a prediction? mean how I will serve? what will be the form of input?

Comment: @Abdul Rehman - just a comment on your results: you have an imbalanced dataset (5% fraud rate) and I presume you are mostly interested in detecting fraud, so using `clf.predict()` and a metric such as accuracy may not be very useful.  For example, your LOF has an accuracy of 91% but you are only actually detecting 1/5 frauds because accuracy treats both cases as equal. You could have achieved 95% accuracy by classifying everything as 0. Try using predict_proba() to give a rank order and then something like a ROC curve, so you can understand whether you need to move your detection threshold.

Comment: Hi @Stev, you raised a good point, can you guide me a little bit further how can I implement `predict_proba()`  in my case? please!